# Can't generate Nuxt website with @googlemaps/js-api-loader

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-maps, nuxt.js, vercel

I am using `@googlemaps/js-api-loader` in my Nuxt 3 website. Everything works fine in local development, but when I try to build the project with `nuxt generate` (no matter if locally or on Vercel) I'm getting following error:

```
[nuxt] [request error] Named export 'Loader' not found. The requested module 'file:///path/to/website/node_modules/@googlemaps/js-api-loader/dist/index.umd.js' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports. CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using:
```

The important part of loading script looks like this:

```js
import { Loader } from '@googlemaps/js-api-loader';

const loader = new Loader({
    apiKey: config.googleMapsApiKey,
    version: 'weekly',
});

onMounted(async() => {
    await loader
        .load()

        ...
```

so I tried to import this package differently, e.g.:

```
import * as gmaps from '@googlemaps/js-api-loader';
const { Loader } = gmaps;
```

and the previous error disappeared, but now I'm getting

```
[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of setup function
  at <DynamicLocations class="contact__map" locations= [
  {
    id: 1,

...


[nuxt] [request error] gmaps.Loader is not a constructor
  at setup (./.nuxt/prerender/chunks/app/server.mjs:5536:20)  
  at _sfc_main$t.setup (./.nuxt/prerender/chunks/app/server.mjs:5582:25)  
  at callWithErrorHandling (./.nuxt/prerender/chunks/renderer.mjs:2654:23)  
  at setupStatefulComponent (./.nuxt/prerender/chunks/renderer.mjs:9548:30)  
  at setupComponent (./.nuxt/prerender/chunks/renderer.mjs:9503:12)  
  at renderComponentVNode (./.nuxt/prerender/chunks/renderer.mjs:12068:17)  
  at Object.ssrRenderComponent (./.nuxt/prerender/chunks/renderer.mjs:12504:12)  
  at ./.nuxt/prerender/chunks/app/server.mjs:5628:36  
  at renderComponentSubTree (./.nuxt/prerender/chunks/renderer.mjs:12149:13)  
  at renderComponentVNode (./.nuxt/prerender/chunks/renderer.mjs:12084:16)
```

I also can't import package by default export. Do you have any ideas what's going on and how can I fix this?

Comment: Importing the entire library worked for me, which of course is not ideal. I opened an issue on GH. https://github.com/googlemaps/js-api-loader/issues/692

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a [documentation page](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/esm#troubleshooting-esm-issues) related to this problem and there is the following information:

> If you encounter these errors, the issue is almost certainly with the upstream library. They need to fix their library to support being imported by Node.

Although they provide a solution to get rid of errors by adding the package to `build.transpile`:

```
 build: {
     transpile: ['@googlemaps/js-api-loader'],
 },
```

It worked for me

Comment: Thank you so much! You made my day! The documentation page link is broken BTW. This is the newer one: https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/esm#troubleshooting-esm-issues. I've tried to edit it, but it seems to be "to many pending edits on Stack Overflow", so it can't be done now.